# Change the unknown factor

Tags: exponential-function

I need help with an equation that was given me, but I need to change the unknown factor.

So far, the equation is A=7*B^0.2

However, A is known and the unknown factor is B. How do I change this equation into the form of B=... ?

Thank you very much, all help is appreciated.

Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutpiplying by $\frac{1}{7}$ to both sides:

$$
B^{0.2} = \frac{1}{7} \cdot A
$$

and now since $\frac{1}{5} = 0.2$, elevating to the fith power to both sides leaves us with

$$
B = B^1 = (B^{0.2})^5 = \frac{1}{7^5}A^5 = (\frac{A}{7})^5
$$

Answer (score 0):

First notice that $0.2= 1/5$, so your starting point is
$$ A=7B^{\frac{1}{5}}.$$
Divide both sides by $7$ to get
$$ \frac{A}{7}=B^{\frac{1}{5}}. $$
Finally, exponentiate both sides to the power of $5$ to get
$$ \left(\frac{A}{7}\right)^5=B. $$